# include a list view in quick action

Tags: android, android-listview, quickaction

I am trying to create a Quick Action dialog for a button in which I want to include  an image button and a list view.

Code Snippet:

```
lv=new ListView(this);
        ArrayAdapter<String> myad=new ArrayAdapter<String>(QuickActionActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myList);
        lv.setAdapter(myad);

        ActionItem myicon=new ActionItem(ID_DOWN,getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_ok));
        quickAction.addActionItem(myicon);
ActionItem mixlist=new ActionItem();
        mixlist.setActionId(ID_UP);
        mixlist.setLv(lv);

        quickAction.addActionItem(mixlist);
```

Is this the right way to do this?